# how to Register an Event of Dynamically created element in HTML using JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have added following table dynamically using Javascript:

```
    <table class="ActionMenu">
<tr>
<td>
<p>Ghanshyam</p>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

i want to get alert on Click of this table..

I tried:

```
$('body').on("click", ".ActionMenu tr", function (e) {
      alert("abcd");
 });

$('.ActionMenu ').on("click", "tr", function(){
   //do something
});

$('.ActionMenu').live('click',function(){});

$('#ActionTab').delegate('.someClass','click',function(){});
```

but none of the following Method work..
how can i achive my goal?
Thanks

Comment: Perhaps a jsfiddle would be helpful in this case, if my answer doesn't help

Comment: the first `.on` statement should work fine. Maybe the problem is elsewhere

Comment: `$('.ActionMenu').live('click',function(){});` works: http://jsfiddle.net/QMNcc/. Maybe you could reproduce your bug in a [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)

Comment: I am deploying it on Server side, and it is not working

Comment: `.live` is obsolete, use `.on`. The problem here is that the event is bound to `$('body')` in the first case, and the third case doesn't alert anything, making it hard to see if the event was handled :)

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem I think you mean depricated - it still works and can still be used. In JQuery 1.7 the `live` method just calls the `on` method itself (making it backward compatable). There is no mention of the version of JQuery being used, which could be why `on` is not working.

Comment: @MyHeadHurts: you're absolutely right, I stand corrected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your selectors are a tad off, at first glance, try:

```
$('table.ActionMenu tr').on('click',callback);
```

Since this isn't working: a couple of things have been suggested:

- What version of jQuery are you using, `on` might not be working if you're on an old version
- have you tried `$(body).on('click', '.ActionMenu tr', function() { alert('clicked'); });`? Replacing `.on` with `.live` if needed.
- A classic problem, but easily forgotten: have you checked for typo's in either class names, id's... on both sides (server & jQuery)? --You never know
- Is all code wrapped in a `$(document).ready(function(){/*script goes here...*/});`
- Check you console for possible syntax errors or other messages

Comment: but this won't work on tables injected later via ajax/javascript

Comment: Yes, it will... `.on` is incorporates the same functionality as `.live`, so the event handler will be bound to all dynamically generated elements, too

Comment: Thanks for you answer but where can i put my Content Code in your above method?

Comment: the `callback` can be any function reference, either previously declared, but feel free to replace that with `function(){alert($(this).html());}` or whatever you need

Answer (score 2):

are you enclosed your code in `$(document).ready()` block ?  if not then try to enclose inside document.ready function

```
$(function(){
$('body').on("click", ".ActionMenu tr", function (e) {
      alert("abcd");
 });

$('.ActionMenu ').on("click", "tr", function(){
   //do something
});

$('.ActionMenu').live('click',function(){});

$('#ActionTab').delegate('.someClass','click',function(){});
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document.body).on('click', '.ActionMenu tr', function() { alert('clicked'); });
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/MWvMH/1/